# Store multiple 2D matrices in an array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I'm trying to store multiple matrices into an array (each matrix has the same dimension), and I think my logic is correct, but the code isn't running correctly. My inputs from the text file look like this (for example):

```
0 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0

0000000000
00      00
0000000000

000 00 000
00 000 00 
000 00 000
```

So in the example, each ' ' counts as a character which I convert to a -1, and each new lines is a new matrix. I've already found the number of rows and columns, and I'm told the number of pairs I will see in the text file. So I want to make an array like this

```
pairs[number of pairs][rows][columns].
```

So in this example, it would be pairs[3][3][10] so 3 samples each with a 3 x 10 matrix. My code is:

```
int lines = 0;
BufferedReader brr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
        //now read and store in 2D matrix
        int[][][] samples = new int[pairs][rows][cols];
        while((lines = brr.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line > 2) { // to skip first 3 lines of text file
                for (int i = 0; i < pairs; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < lines.length(); k++) {
                            //Cycle through each character in line
                            if (lines.charAt(k) == 'O' || lines.charAt(k) == '0') {
                                samples[i][j][k] = 1; //store in the matrix as a 1
                            }
                            else if (lines.charAt(k) == ' ') {

                                samples[i][j][k] = -1;
                                //store spaces as -1
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            line++;
        }
        br.close();
```

Sorry, I meant to write my output, but right now it's assigning the variables, but it continues to repeat. What I mean is that once it finishes the 3rd input, the for loops just repeat again. In other words, once i = 2 (in this example), and j = 2, k = 2, it then repeats and everything goes through again from the beginning for some reason.

Comment: `"...but the code isn't running correctly"` -- but you neglect to tell us *how* your code is not running correctly. Consider doing this, but first have you done basic debugging yet? This may be achieved by simply sprinkling your code  with a bunch of println statements that tell you what values your variables hold.

Comment: And your code seems to be mixing and confusing use of `line` and `lines`. It declares an int variable `lines` but then assigns a String to it?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry about that, I realized that after I submitted, but I edited the code. line is just a count, i can replace that with count = 0 and count++ but it doesn't change anything. I think I might not be accounting for the new lines in between looking at my code again

Comment: nvm I figured out what I was doing wrong. I'll update my code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out what was happening, I wasn't accounting for the new line in between each pair. So the working code is:

```
BufferedReader brr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
            //now read and store in 2D matrix
            int[][][] samples = new int[inVals.get(1)][rows][cols];
            int index = 0;
            while((lines = brr.readLine()) != null) {
                if (curr > 2) {                    
                    if (lines.equals("")) {
                            index++; //increment the pair we're on
                        }
                            for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                                for (int k = 0; k < lines.length(); k++) {
                                    //Cycle through each character in line
                                    if (lines.charAt(k) == 'O' || lines.charAt(k) == '0') {
                                        samples[index][j][k] = 1;
                                    }
                                    else if (lines.charAt(k) == ' ') {
                                        samples[index][j][k] = -1;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    }
                    curr++; //for the current line we're reading
                }
                brr.close(); //close buffered reader
```